# Different way of proving optimal substructure?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

For the optimal substructure property, it states that an optimal solution for a given problem can be obtained by combining optimal solutions of its subproblems.

We can write this as Opt(given problem) = f(Opt(subproblem 1), Opt(subproblem 2), ...). Where f combines optimal solutions to the subproblems.

Usually, to prove optimal substructure, we show that if $Opt(given problem)$ is in fact an optimal solution, then Opt(subproblem 1), Opt(subproblem 2), ..., are also all optimal. This is seen for example in the Cormen (CLRS) book.

My question is: can we prove the converse? That is, we show that if Opt(subproblem 1), Opt(subproblem 2), ..., are all optimal, then Opt(given problem) is also optimal?

Comment: It depends. "Optimal substructure" is not a fully instantiated mathematical definition.

Comment: So either way works then?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: I'm trying to prove the property of optimal structure as stated in CLRS or other algorithm textbooks.